# Why an auto incremented column in datatable is coming empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, webforms

I have made an identity column **id** with an auto-incremented equals **true** in datatable but it's empty.

Why ?

```
        Datatable dt= new datatable();

        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));

        dc.AutoIncrement = true;
        dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn("NITNo", typeof(string));
        dc.DefaultValue = txtNitNo.Text.ToString();
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn("WorkNo", typeof(string));
        dc.DefaultValue = txtWorkNo.Text.ToString();
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        //dt.Rows.rem

        //Bind Data to GridView
        gvBOQ.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        gvBOQ.DataSource = dt;
        gvBOQ.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add data to the DataTable, you have to make sure that the value in the Identity Column is `null`

```
//create a datatable
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//auto increment column
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
table.Columns.Add(column);

//add a normal column
column = new DataColumn("value", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(column);

//add some data to the table
table.Rows.Add(null, "Netherlands");
table.Rows.Add(null, "Japan");
table.Rows.Add(99, "Australia");
table.Rows.Add(null, "America");
```

The resulting table will look like this

```
id  value
1   Netherlands
2   Japan
99  Australia
100 America
```

Comment: hello, thanks sorry but I cannot insert fake data because it would disturb the original data and might result in making problems at client end.

Comment: The fake data is just for demo. The important thing is dat the id column is left empty when filling the datatable.

Comment: can you modify my code because i am totally new to it.

Comment: There is not much to modify. You just add data to the datatable and bind it to the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the datatable and increment the value of the particular column
e.g

```
int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
   dr["id"] = i;
   i++;
}
```